# Elixir alias on a submodule

Tags: module, alias, elixir

According to http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html#aliases

I should be able to have this code working:

```
defmodule A do
  alias A.B, as: C

  defmodule B do
    defstruct name: ""
  end
end
```

`iex(1)> %C{}`

But instead i'm having this error:

`** (CompileError) iex:1: C.__struct__/0 is undefined, cannot expand struct C`

Any idea of what i'm missing here ?

**Edit:** Module naming is simplified here for the exemple

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works only for the module in which the alias is defined, e.g.:

```
defmodule A do
  alias A.B, as: C

  defmodule B do
    defstruct name: ""
  end

  def new do
    %C{}
  end
end
```

You could then do:

```
iex(6)> A.new
%A.B{name: ""}
```

This will also work in iex if you type the alias there:

```
iex(7)> alias A.B, as: C
nil
iex(8)> %C{}
%A.B{name: ""}
```